# Get Custom attribute in API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap-api-v2

```
<?php  require_once "app/Mage.php";

    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
    $installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
    // change details below:
    $attribute  = array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'label'=> 'IceCatID',
        'input' => 'text',
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default' => "",
        'group' => "General Information"
    );
    $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'IceCatID', $attribute);
    $installer->endSetup();?>
```

I created Custom attribute for category it's working fine but how to get api in this custom attribute we are developing Android App.

Comment: can you telll me you are need which api method only category list or info???

Comment: Let us assume i have one text box i set 0 i want to get that 0 in api also

Comment: @Kothari,Which api you are using?

Comment: Soap api using in andriod team

Answer (score 9):

If you're using the SOAP Api try this:

- Create a basic custom module and ensure that has `<Mage_Catalog/>` as dependency

Then add an api config file for overwrite the "category" complex types definitions:

> app/code/{pool}/{vendor}/{module}/etc/**wsdl.xml**

And add this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
        <complexType name="catalogCategoryEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="category_id" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="parent_id" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="is_active" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="position" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="level" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="children" type="typens:ArrayOfCatalogCategoryEntities"/>

                <!-- ADD YOUR ATTRIBUTE TO ANY DESIRED NODE -->
                <!-- CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE -->  
                <element name="ice_cat_id" type="xsd:int"/>
                <!-- CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE -->

            </all>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="catalogCategoryEntityNoChildren">
            <all>
                <element name="category_id" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="parent_id" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="is_active" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="position" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="level" type="xsd:int"/>
            </all>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="ArrayOfCatalogCategoryEntitiesNoChildren">
            <complexContent>
                <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                    <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:catalogCategoryEntityNoChildren[]"/>
                </restriction>
            </complexContent>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="catalogCategoryTree">
            <all>
                <element name="category_id" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="parent_id" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="position" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="level" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="children" type="typens:ArrayOfCatalogCategoryEntities"/>
            </all>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="catalogCategoryEntityCreate">
            <all>
                <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="is_active" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="position" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                <!-- position parameter is deprecated, category anyway will be positioned in the end of list
                    and you can not set position directly, use catalog_category.move instead -->
                <element name="available_sort_by" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_design" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_design_apply" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_design_from" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_design_to" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_layout_update" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="default_sort_by" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="display_mode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="is_anchor" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="landing_page" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="meta_description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="meta_keywords" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="meta_title" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="page_layout" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="url_key" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="include_in_menu" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
            </all>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="catalogCategoryInfo">
            <all>
                <element name="category_id" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="is_active" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="position" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="level" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="parent_id" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="all_children" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="children" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="created_at" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="updated_at" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="url_key" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="meta_title" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="meta_keywords" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="meta_description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="path" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="url_path" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="children_count" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="display_mode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="is_anchor" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="available_sort_by" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_design" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_design_apply" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_design_from" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_design_to" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="page_layout" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_layout_update" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="default_sort_by" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="landing_page" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
            </all>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
  </types>
</definitions>
```

This is the full list of all category related nodes/actions so add your attribute to any of them. (I just added it to catalogCategoryEntity)

**NOTES**

- By convention your attribute code should be `ice_cat_id` instead `IceCatID` you can still using "IceCatID" for label.
- Keep just the modified `<complex type>`nodes in your wsdl file.
- Clean Config/WSDL Cache(s) and if you don't see the changes just restart php to flush php wsdl cache.

**EDIT: About WSDL Definition in Magento**
To clarify some concept:

We are using the WSDL Configuration to update `<complexType>` definitions. Every `<complexType>` **node** defines a data type that isn't standard (like 'int')

Every SOAP call has it own definition, if you make a call to [catalogCategoryInfo](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.info.html): you will get a response body with a node called 'info' as defined here:

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/wsdl.xml

```
    ...
    <message name="catalogCategoryInfoRequest">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
        <part name="categoryId" type="xsd:int"/>
        <part name="storeView" type="xsd:string"/>
        <part name="attributes" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
    </message>
    <message name="catalogCategoryInfoResponse">
        <part name="info" type="typens:catalogCategoryInfo"/>
    </message>
    ...
```

This Service definition is telling us that requests to **catalogCategoryInfo** will give us a node called **"info"** of the **catalogCategoryInfo** type. This means that if you need your custom attribute for that call *(catalogCategoryInfo)* you have to add your attribute to the type definition *(in your module wsdl.xml file)*:

> app/code/{pool}/{vendor}/{module}/etc/wsdl.xml (part)

```
        ...
        <complexType name="catalogCategoryInfo">
            <all>
                <!-- MY CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE -->
                <element name="ice_cat_id" type="xsd:int"/>
                <!-- MY CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE -->
                <element name="category_id" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="is_active" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="position" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="level" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="parent_id" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="all_children" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="children" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="created_at" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="updated_at" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="url_key" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="meta_title" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="meta_keywords" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="meta_description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="path" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="url_path" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="children_count" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="display_mode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="is_anchor" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="available_sort_by" type="typens:ArrayOfString" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_design" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_design_apply" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_design_from" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_design_to" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="page_layout" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="custom_layout_update" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="default_sort_by" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="landing_page" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
            </all>
        </complexType>
        ...
```

Looking at the `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/wsdl.xml`file you will find which `<compleType>` definition *node* must edit for each message (When I say "add your attribute to every needed node" means that). So the workaround to do it would be something like that:

1. Determine which SOAP service I need to consume.
2. Find that service response definition in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/wsdl.xml`
3. Look at that definition and Find which  node I need to modify.
4. Use our `app/code/{pool}/{vendor}/{module}/etc/wsdl.xml` file to overwrite the  definition (adding our custom attribute(s) there).
5. Clean Magento Cache
6. Clean Php Wsdl cache (or simply restart php service)

Note that the same workaround could be used if you want to remove some unused attributes to perform fastest requests.

**EDIT 2: Missing Attributes for some methods**

I forgot to mention that for some API methods the WSDL definition rewrite isn't enough. these methods are:

- **catalogCategoryTree**
- **catalogCategoryLevel**

In both cases the category data is actually loaded by collection so you need to rewrite these methods in order to get your custom attribute available in the response.

> To add an attribute to the **catalogCategoryTree** API method

First we have to overwrite the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api::tree`  method:

```
public function tree($parentId = null, $store = null)
{
    if (is_null($parentId) && !is_null($store)) {
        $parentId = Mage::app()->getStore($this->_getStoreId($store))->getRootCategoryId();
    } elseif (is_null($parentId)) {
        $parentId = 1;
    }

    /* @var $tree Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Tree */
    $tree = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_tree')
        ->load();

    $root = $tree->getNodeById($parentId);

    if($root && $root->getId() == 1) {
        $root->setName(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Root'));
    }

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($this->_getStoreId($store))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
        // Custom Attribute
        ->addAttributeToSelect('ice_cat_id');

    $tree->addCollectionData($collection, true);

    return $this->_nodeToArray($root);
}
```

Then we need to modify the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api::_nodeToArray` method too since return data is hardcoded:

```
protected function _nodeToArray(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node)
{
    // Only basic category data
    $result = array();
    $result['category_id'] = $node->getId();
    $result['parent_id']   = $node->getParentId();
    $result['name']        = $node->getName();
    $result['is_active']   = $node->getIsActive();
    $result['position']    = $node->getPosition();
    $result['level']       = $node->getLevel();
    $result['children']    = array();

    // Custom Attribute
    $result['ice_cat_id']  = $node->getIceCatId();

    foreach ($node->getChildren() as $child) {
        $result['children'][] = $this->_nodeToArray($child);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

> To add an attribute to the **catalogCategoryLevel** API method

We need to modify the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api::level`

```
public function level($website = null, $store = null, $categoryId = null)
{
    $ids = array();
    $storeId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DEFAULT_STORE_ID;

    // load root categories of website
    if (null !== $website) {
        try {
            $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website);
            if (null === $store) {
                if (null === $categoryId) {
                    foreach ($website->getStores() as $store) {
                        /* @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
                        $ids[] = $store->getRootCategoryId();
                    }
                } else {
                    $ids = $categoryId;
                }
            } elseif (in_array($store, $website->getStoreIds())) {
                $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getId();
                $ids = (null === $categoryId)? $store->getRootCategoryId() : $categoryId;
            } else {
                $this->_fault('store_not_exists');
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('website_not_exists', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    elseif (null !== $store) {
        // load children of root category of store
        if (null === $categoryId) {
            try {
                $store = Mage::app()->getStore($store);
                $storeId = $store->getId();
                $ids = $store->getRootCategoryId();
            } catch (Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception $e) {
                $this->_fault('store_not_exists');
            }
        }
        // load children of specified category id
        else {
            $storeId = $this->_getStoreId($store);
            $ids = (int)$categoryId;
        }
    }
    // load all root categories
    else {
        $ids = (null === $categoryId)? Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID : $categoryId;
    }

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active')
        // ---
        // CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE
        ->addAttributeToSelect('ice_cat_id');

    if (is_array($ids)) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $ids));
    } else {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $ids);
    }

    // Only basic category data
    $result = array();
    foreach ($collection as $category) {
        /* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
        $result[] = array(
            'category_id' => $category->getId(),
            'parent_id'   => $category->getParentId(),
            'name'        => $category->getName(),
            'is_active'   => $category->getIsActive(),
            'position'    => $category->getPosition(),
            'level'       => $category->getLevel()
            // ---
            // CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE
            'ice_cat_id'  => $category->getIceCatId()
        );
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Alternatively you can overwrite hook the event `catalog_category_collection_save_after` and add your attribute by default every time the collection is loaded but you will still need to change the `_nodeToArray()` and `level` methods.

Comment: Good attempt @MauroNigrele

Comment: @AmitBera thanks! is actually a "working example" i did it that way several times.

Comment: Can i use this ice_cat_id or IceCatID. can you please update that working module

Comment: @kothari which part?

Comment: we used IceCatID for all place(wsdl.xml & api.php) after that i got null value only that what i am asking can you please update that module or i need to use ice_cat_id for all

Comment: The usage of attribute codea in_that_way is a recommendation or convention i'm not sure if in the wsdl configuration you can use or not the attribute in 'Title Case' . So the short answer is change the attribute code to ice_cat_id to be 100% sure

Comment: Can you please update that code with that module i tried but it's not working

Comment: i added above code in wsdl but it's not showing

Comment: Looking at your code, the attribute code is "IceCatID", using capital letters for a code seems like a very bad idea. I'd recommend you to delete the attribute & create again, using only lowercase letters. And then, try again Mauro solution

Comment: The code here it's working but you need to make your part: 1) create your module and attribute 2) add your attribute field to every needed node in the wsdl 3) clean caches and load wsdl... You should see your attribute in the category node.

Comment: How to clean caches and load wsdl also i can't understand this  every needed node in the wsdl

Comment: @Kothari take a look at the updated Answer

Comment: i added this code <element name="ice_cat_id" type="xsd:int"/> in wsdl.xml file then i clear cache and wsdl cache still it's showing null only

Comment: Which soap method are you using?

Comment: i just add app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/wsdl.xml this file under catalogCategoryInfo it enough right?

Comment: we are using Soap v2 api

Comment: No, You shouldn't modify the core wsdl file (unless you do it for testing porpouses), I asked you about soap method not version. In catalogCategoryInfo the attribute value should be present since each category is loaded but if you are using the catalogCategoryTree method you will need to modify the api model too because a single collection is loaded. Please check with the android team which soap method are using

Comment: Ok actually android team using Soap v2

Comment: Ok SoapV2 is the **api** i'm asking about which SoapV2 **method** are you calling from android... this is the methods list http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalogCategory.html - if you take a look at `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Api.php` and `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Api/V2.php` you will find how data is loaded and retrieved and you may want to debug such data in order to verify if your attribute is present there. BTW have you already changed the attribute code to 'ice_cat_id'?

Comment: @Kothari i'll update the answer to add some missing data about data loading for some methods

Comment: @Kothari i've updated the answer take a look please

Comment: We are using "catalogCategoryTree" api to get tree. We tried to add extra attribute to this api in api.php we are gtting null.

Comment: @Gururaj in my last edit i've added some caveats for this method, you have to load and map the data in `Api.php` and add the attribute to the WSDL definition too.

Comment: @MauroNigrele we followed as told above but we are getting exception org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@70e067e) .

Comment: @Gururaj I can't help you with that exception, please try to debug the raw xml output of the API and the return value of the  `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api::tree` to figure out what is happen. and remember that the SOAP clients tends to cache the WSDL definition too, it's better to follow the changes we are making just step by step from bottom to top because API customs has several potential fail points.

Comment: We are new from this can you please tell where excetly check

Comment: Sure: you can start logging: in _nodeToArray() before `return $result;` Mage::log($result); this will output the $result contents to var/log/system.log

Comment: protected function _nodeToArray(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node) {       
$result = array(); $result['category_id'] = $node->getId();       $result['parent_id']   = $node->getParentId();$result['name']        = $node->getName();$result['is_active']   = $node->getIsActive();
$result['position']    = $node->getPosition();$result['level']       = $node->getLevel();$result['children']    = array();$result['ice_cat_id']  = $node->getIceCatId();foreach ($node->getChildren() as $child) {
$result['children'][] = $this->_nodeToArray($child);}
Mage::log($result);return $result;}

Comment: is it corret but didn't print any thing in log file

Comment: `$test = $result; unset($test['children']); Mage::log($test)`

Comment: After add this i need to clear cache ???

Comment: 2016-01-09T20:46:26+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected  in /var/www/html/domain/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php on line 363

Comment: cache Management is disabled and Enable WSDL Cache --> Yes is it any problem

Comment: The warning comes after the inclusion of the debug log?, comment out that line(s) and test again... Mage::log() should log without print any output, I mean the headers warning should be generated by another error. - About Cache - if you are using php 5.5.X as come - in the box - you probably have enable op_cache so just flush all magento caches and restart php between any change

Comment: no there is no error it was in previous

Comment: @Kothari I'm absolutly lost with this since I don't know/understand what are you doing, so please can update the question with the current code state. I'm doing my best to help you but it's impossible that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35007/discussion-between-mauronigrele-and-kothari).

Answer (score -1):

Accessing and new value from API has following steps

1) Create attribute from magento admin or through magento setup script
2) define the attribute in wsdl , now you have two thing i.e request and response
2.1) For request part you can put the value in Mage/Catalog/etc/wsdl.xml

Ex: The following is sample for Request,if you have already have wsdl.xml in your module which is preferred

```
    <!-- CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE -->  
            <element name="IceCatID" type="xsd:int"/>
            <!-- CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE -->

                <element name="children" type="typens:ArrayOfCatalogCategoryEntities"/>
            </all>
        </complexType>
```

Clear the cache and type you wsdl url in browser to see if the new attribute is showing up under catalogCategoryEntity, which mean you now have given provision to transfer data between two systems

3) Once you are done with step2, now you need to go to api.php in you module ,usually at your_module/model/api.php or whatever the model you have setup in your_module/et/api.xml

4) Go to respective method which you have mapped in api.xml

Ex:

public function create($categoryData)
   {
    //To see what values are there
        var_dump($categoryData);

```
    /** @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->setStoreId(0)
        ->load($categoryData['category_id']);
```

$category->setData('IceCatID','your value for IceCatID');

}

you can refer http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-api-in-magento-part-one--cms-23785 for Custom module for API

Hope this helps