# Get custom attribute back using SOAP v2

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

Using Magento v1.9.2.3

I'm working on a simple cash register written in C# and using a barcode scanner.
We have already added the barcode as a new attribute to all our products.

I want to get all my products using the SOAPv2 API and save it in a local SQLite. When a barcode is scanned I can look in the database for the price. Seems simple enough.

I already figured out how to get the product data. First I use the `catalogProductList` to get a list of all my products. Next I use `catalogProductList` to get more details of a product, including the price.
Using `catalogProductAttributeSetList` I can get all my attribute sets. Next I can get all the attributes in a set using `catalogProductAttributeSetList`. Now I know the `attribute_id` of my barcode attribute. But I can't figure out how to get the value of that attribute in my product.

I did read this [Get Custom attribute in API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98184/get-custom-attribute-in-api) and I truly hope I don't need to mess with Magento and PHP to get this working.

Please let me know if I can read the value of my custom attribute without messing with Magento en PHP.

Comment: Paul, first you use , catalogProductList and then  catalogProductList ?

That is twice the same call, but i think that is not what you do. 

Do you receive the information with,   catalogProductInfo ?

Comment: Paul, first you use , catalogProductList and then  catalogProductList ?

That is twice the same call, but i think that is not what you do. 

Do you receive the information with,   catalogProductInfo ? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html.

You can add the extra attributes with; catalogProductRequestAttributes
Exampe;
https://lornajane.net/posts/2010/retrieving-product-attributes-from-magentos-v2-api

Comment: Thanks Evrijn for the link to the example. With it I can read my barcode:
`var attributes = new catalogProductRequestAttributes {additional_attributes = new[] {"barcode"}};`
`var productInfo = _magentoService.catalogProductInfo(_magentoLogin, _productId, null, attributes, null);`
Please submit as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer;

You can add extra attributrs to catalogProductInfo,  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html

More information; https://lornajane.net/posts/2010/retrieving-product-attributes-from-magentos-v2-api

Example code for additional_attributes;

var attributes = new catalogProductRequestAttributes {additional_attributes = new[] {"barcode"}};

var productInfo = _magentoService.catalogProductInfo(_magentoLogin, _productId, null, attributes, null)